# How to add zero-width space after every third uppercase letter in XSLT?

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

I wants to add zero-width space after every third uppercase letter in XSLT.
Here I want to select all the text nodes in the document and filter upper case words among that text nodes.

My XML sample code is:

```
<doc>
    <front>
        <lable>this is a TEST TEXT</lable>
        <para>This is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
    </front>
    <middle>
        <lable>this is a TEST TEXT</lable>
        <para>This is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
    </middle>
    <back>
        <lable>This is a TEST TEXT</lable>
        <para>This is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
    </back>
</doc>
```

The XSLT I wrote is:

```
<xsl:template match="*/text()" priority="100">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^[A-Z]+">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:variable name="upperWord" select="substring(.,3)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($upperWord,'&#x200b;')"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>

            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

The output I am expecting:

```
<doc>
            <front>
                <lable>this is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T</lable>
                <para>​his is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T with UPP&#x200b;ER and Lower</para>
            </front>
            <front>
                <lable>this is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T</lable>
                <para>​his is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T with UPP&#x200b;ER and Lower</para>
            </front>
            <front>
                <lable>this is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T</lable>
                <para>​his is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T with UPP&#x200b;ER and Lower</para>
            </front>
        </doc>

    Output I got:

<doc>
        <front>
            <lable>this is a TEST TEXT</lable>
            <para>​his is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
        </front>
        <middle>
            <lable>this is a TEST TEXT</lable>
            <para>​his is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
        </middle>
        <back>
            <lable>​his is a TEST TEXT</lable>
            <para>​his is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
        </back>
    </doc>
```

Here, I can't understand the why uppercase first letter of the word is selected and Why all the text nodes are not selected.
Could someone help me to resolve this issue..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing

```
regex="^[A-Z]+"
```

with

```
regex="[A-Z]+"
```

Comment: Thanks Vegenta..regex is working well by replacing this..but my question is not totally solved

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify it by dropping the `xsl:analyze-string` and just using `replace()`.

Note: In my example I'm using `xsl:character-map` to preserve the entity in the text. You can strip that and the actual character will be inserted.

Example... (<kbd>[working version here](http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mQ)</kbd>)

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <front>
        <lable>this is a TEST TEXT</lable>
        <para>This is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
    </front>
    <middle>
        <lable>this is a TEST TEXT</lable>
        <para>This is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
    </middle>
    <back>
        <lable>This is a TEST TEXT</lable>
        <para>This is a TEST TEXT with UPPER and Lower</para>
    </back>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="chars"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:character-map name="chars">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#x200b;" string="&amp;#x200b;"/>
  </xsl:character-map>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'([A-Z]{3})','$1&#x200b;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <front>
      <lable>this is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T</lable>
      <para>This is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T with UPP&#x200b;ER and Lower</para>
   </front>
   <middle>
      <lable>this is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T</lable>
      <para>This is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T with UPP&#x200b;ER and Lower</para>
   </middle>
   <back>
      <lable>This is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T</lable>
      <para>This is a TES&#x200b;T TEX&#x200b;T with UPP&#x200b;ER and Lower</para>
   </back>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thanks..This is working..Could you please explain me why this xsl:analyze-string is giving me incorrect solution?

Comment: @user2490093 - It's because your regex is matching one or more uppercase letters anchored to the beginning of the string. Then you use `substring()` to start at the 3rd character of the match. So if the string starts with `This` the match is just `T` and a substring starting at the 3rd character returns nothing. The zero width space is getting output though; you just can't see it.

Comment: @user2490093 - let me know if you still want an `xsl:analyze-string` answer. Otherwise, if this answer is sufficient, please accept it by clicking on the check mark (✅) next to it.